# User ether.js mnemonic for bitcoin

Tags: ether, wallets, ethereumjs, bitcoin, hd-wallets

I'm using `Ether.js` for my react native app to create mnemonic.
i want use `Wallet.fromMnemonic(code, path)` to get key pairs but when i send bitcoin Derivation Path i get and ethereum private key which is started with 0x.Is there any way to use `ether.js` to get other coin key pairs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot use `ethers.js` to generate a Bitcoin key pair. Most Bitcoin and Ethereum wallets use the same standard though ([BIP-32](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki) and [BIP-39](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki)), so you can simply use one of the other libraries that implement this functionality, like [`bitcoinjs-lib`](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib).

There is an example using `bitcoinjs-lib` here: https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib/blob/master/test/integration/bip32.js#L85